# Parallel testing on iOS devices using Appium

Tags: selenium, testng, appium, selenium-grid, ios-ui-automation

I would like to run my automation scripts parallelly on multiple iOS devices using Appium. I can able to perform this parallel test on Android but not on iOS.

Is there any way we can perform this on iOS.

Tools I am using are: Selenium Grid, Appium with TestNG framework.

Comment: can you please send me your android configuration ? I'm looking to setup appium to run against 3 real android device. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible by using Selenium Grid. But You must be aware that Apple has a limitation that only 1 iOS device can be attached to 1 MAC device. So e.g. if you have 3 iOS devices each connected to separate MAC you must launch appium node on each MAC for the particular device and link it to the central Selenium Grid instance.
And after that just launch your tests just as you would do in the Android case.

Comment: Update, you can now connect multiple iOS devices in Mac. I am able to run parallel successfully using appium on a single Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work across android and ios. But appium server should be running in a MAC.

```
  //Have your setup(Eclipse,Android SDK, ioswebkit proxy, Appium) installed in MAC for instance 10.10
    //create an instance with your thread to generalize for both android and ios


    public LaunchAppiumServer(){

        public synchronized void startiOSWebKitProxy(String UDID,String debugProxy,String platform){
                if(Settings.getProperty("testbed").equals("localbrowser") && !Settings.getProperty("LOCAL_SETTINGS").contains("Emulator")){         
                    if(platform.equals("ios")){
                        //Webkit Proxy command          
                        CommandLine iOSProxyCommand = new CommandLine("ios_webkit_debug_proxy");
                        iOSProxyCommand.addArgument("-c");
                        iOSProxyCommand.addArgument(UDID+":"+debugProxy);
                        iOSProxyCommand.addArgument("-F");

                        DefaultExecuteResultHandler iOSProxyresultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
                        DefaultExecutor iOSProxyexecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
                        iOSProxyexecutor.setExitValue(1);
                        try {
                            iOSProxyexecutor.execute(iOSProxyCommand, iOSProxyresultHandler);
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            System.out.println("iOS Proxy started in :"+ deviceName);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }  

         public synchronized void startAppiumServer(String UDID,String port,String  platform,String debugProxy) throws Exception{
              CommandLine command = new CommandLine("appium");
                    command.addArgument("--udid");  
                    command.addArgument(UDID);
                    command.addArgument("--address", false);
                    command.addArgument("127.0.0.1");
                    command.addArgument("--port", false);
                    command.addArgument(port);
                    command.addArgument("--webkit-debug-proxy-port");
                    command.addArgument(debugProxy);
                    command.addArgument("--tmp");
                    command.addArgument("/tmp/appium-"+port);
                    command.addArgument("--full-reset", true);
                    command.addArgument("--log-level", false);
                    command.addArgument("error");
                    command.addArgument("--log", false);
                    Timestamp currentTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
                    command.addArgument("/Users/sethu/Documents/appiumLogs/appium"+currentTimestamp.toString().replace(" ", "")+".log");
                    DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
                    executor.setExitValue(1);
                    try {
                        executor.execute(command, resultHandler);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Unable to Launch Appium Server: ");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Unable to Launch Appium Server: ");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
    }
```